# Pluggable, Extendable and RESTFUL Service Repository in ODATA or ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, rest, odata, asp.net-web-api

I am going to develop a service repository using ODATA. As a result, I can model those public method of those classes as Entity Type with these properties automatically by reflection

- Id. GUID
- Output. It should depend on the type of the method return
- ... (Any other input parameters)

On the other hand, I will also expose these public methods as an Entity Set under the previous defined Entity Type. Finally, public user can invoke the expose services RESTFULLY by POSTing a JSON object to the specific the URI and retrieve OUTPUT from the return JSON object with the help of ODATA protocol

Unfortunately, either Array of Primary Object or Array of Complex Object are not supported in Entity Type definition. As a result, I can't define a SMTP Send Entity Type which will have multiple TO (string[]) or CC (also string[]) How can I deal with this problem?

I heard that Microsoft have announced ODATA V3.0 and ASP.NET Web API. Do these new technology can help? Or any other suggestion for implementation an extendable RESTFUL (or HTTP friendly since I would like to call it in javascript in html, php or any other web pages directly)? Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by Entity Set and Entity Type?  Are those classes you have created? Or are they components of Entity Framework?

Comment: They are terms in ODATA I mean. Maybe they should be called Resource Type or Resource Set in WCF Data Services in .NET

Comment: Not sure what you mean by `RESTful Service Repository`. REST nothing to do with repository or how a service is implemented internally. Also OData is not RESTful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The OData V3 does support properties which are a collection of primitive or complex values. The WCF Data Services V5 implements this for custom and reflection providers (no support for EF providers yet).

See for example http://www.odata.org/media/30002/OData%20Atom%20Format.html#collectionofsimpletypedproperties

The latest WCF Data Services can be downloaded here: http://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.Services

Comment: That's great. That may be the feature which I am looking forward to. Thanks.